# English translation of Ganesh purana

Tags: puranas, translation-request, ganesha, resource

I'm looking to read Ganesh Puran. what is the best-unabridged copy I can get? if I could get a link or author name. it would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is a translation by Greg Bailey, it's part 1 volume is available online 
https://archive.org/details/ABas_the-ganesa-purana-part-1-upasana-khanda/page/n5/mode/2up
Here is the book link which I saw once on some other site https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/complete-ganesa-purana-set-of-3-volumes-nak694/
If you can find the remaining volumes online for free, the ones after the part 1 which I already shared, well and good.